# Не проверяет роли пользователя из jwt на выполнение методов через spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

Есть класс с конфигурацией, где проверяется роль на выполнение определенных endpoint , все работает , jwt формируется , роль записывается в базе и при входе возвращается , но когда я указываю кому что разрешено выполнять , то он этого не делает. Можно указать токен любой роли , хоть админа хоть юзера и метод выполнится. Ошибка forbidden выходит если я слеш где то не правильно укажу , если токен вообще не указать , то будет 401 ошибка , что логично.
В чем может быть проблема ? Как предоставлять использование метода по определенной роли ? На данный момент указание роли бессмысленно. Ошибки в логах нету , роль приходит при выполнении метода , я указал System.out.println(userDetails.getAuthorities()); в классе AuthTokenFilter.
endpoint разные указывал и с ** и * и без них , он на них реагирует, но не на указанные роли.

Класс security :

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
         securedEnabled = true,
         jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;



    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }



    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }




    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
            
                .antMatchers("/api/res/*").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/*").hasRole("ADMIN")

                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

метод authenticationJwtTokenFilter()  класса AuthTokenFilter :

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    // однократное выполнение каждого запроса  API
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {

            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                // из токена получаю email
                String email = jwtUtils.getEmailFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(email);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                System.out.println(userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Не получается настроить аутентификацию пользователя: ", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    // проверка jwt токена по параметру header в заголовке
    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

JwtUtils:

```
public class JwtUtils {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    private String jwtSecret;

    
    private int jwtExpirationMs;

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {

        UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return Jwts.builder().setSubject((userPrincipal.getEmail())).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs)).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }

    public String getEmailFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    // Валидация JWT токена
    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Неверная JWT сигнатура: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Неверный JWT токен: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Срок действия JWT токена истек: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT токен не поддерживается: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT токен пуст: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}



public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    // метод будет запускаться каждый раз, когда не аутентифицированный пользователь запрашивает защищенный HTTP-ресурс
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException {
        logger.error("Ошибка авторизации: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Ошибка! Пользователь не авторизован");
    }
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl:

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    RepositoryUs repositoryUs;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = repositoryUs.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Пользователь с Email: " + email + " не найден"));

        return UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в БД к своим наименованиям ролям ROLE_  так как если вы используете hasRole, то spring security сам его добавляет и проверяет значение с БД (а если там без префиксов ROLE_) то может быть такая ситуация.

И в enum добавьте , где хранятся роли тоже эти префиксы . В security оставьте без них , если используете hasRole